# SSL_CTX_set_cert_store does not increment ref on X509_STORE

Tags: openssl

I am using OpenSSL 1.1.0g and I have a single X509_STORE with all the root CA certs in it. I am creating multiple SSL_CTX objects to serve on multiple ports for incoming connections using different private keys. The SSL_CTX objects will use the single X509_STORE to verify the CA via the SSL_CTX_set_cert_store() function. I noticed that when any of the SSL_CTX objects get free'd via SSL_CTX_free() the ref count on the X509_STORE is decremented and it goes to 0. What I expected is that doing an SSL_CTX_set_cert_store() should add a ref on the X509_STORE object but looking at the OpenSSL source that doesn't seem to be the case. I don't get why on an SSL_CTX_free() it is doing an X509_STORE_free() but never does an X509_STORE_up_ref() when doing the SSL_CTX_set_cert_store() in the first place. The way I'm getting around this is by doing the X509_STORE_up_ref() myself when I do the SSL_CTX_set_cert_store(). However I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design. I don't see the rationale behind it if it is by design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `SSL_CTX_set1_verify_cert_store`.  See RESTRICTIONS under https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_CTX_set_cert_store(3), or more directly, https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_CTX_set1_verify_cert_store(3)

Comment: Thank you I didn't even realize those functions existed. What is the difference between SSL_CTX_set0_verify_cert_store and SSL_CTX_set1_verify_store?

Comment: Hmm. the second link above is now stale.  From https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_set0_verify_cert_store.html: "Those containing a 1 increment the reference count of the supplied store so it must be freed at some point after the operation. Those containing a 0 do not increment reference counts and the supplied store MUST NOT be freed after the operation."

Comment: The documentation is very confusing. There is also a function SSL_CTX_set1_cert_store that increments the reference count on the X509_STORE. What is the difference between SSL_CTX_set1_cert_store vs SSL_CTX_set1_verify_cert_store and SSL_CTX_set1_chain_store?